# 外部へ送信した（しようとしている）情報の監視

Tags: linux, security, monitoring, operating-system, logging

PC(Windows, Mac, Linux)とスマホ（iOS, Android）の両方についての質問ですが、外部に送信した情報を確認したり、これから送信しようとしているものの内容をチェックして必要に応じてブロックしたりといったことはできるのでしょうか？

その際、「暗号化されているから中身を監視できない」というようなことはありますか？

Comment: 何か前提条件が足りていない気がしています。たとえば端末を操作している人がワンタイムパッド暗号を直接入力して情報を送信した場合原理的に平文を監視することはできませんが、質問者さんが問題にしたいものはそういうことではないような気がします。もし可能であれば、なぜ通信をブロックしたいのかの理由を追記して頂けると、問題がより具体的になって建設的な回答が書けると思います。

Answer (score 1):

「外部に送信した情報を確認したり、これから送信しようとしているものの内容をチェックして必要に応じてブロックしたり」するソフトウェアがセキュリティ対策ソフトと呼ばれるのもです。

市販されているセキュリティ対策ソフトは、詳細な情報を取得したり、自分でカスタマイズすることは難しいので、そういうケースでは、[Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) のようなパケット取得・プロトコル解析ソフトを使用します。WiresharkはPC用ですが、スマフォ用のソフトウェアもあります。

パケットを取得した場合には、暗号化されていれば中身は監視できません。HTTPSの場合には、強制的にプロキシサーバを経由させることにより暗号を解読して中身を監視することができます。これをするソフトとしては商用になりますが [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) があります。